# Tests no longer provide the handy links. "run test | debug test" since dev kit change

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, testing, nunit

VS code used to detect my C# tests and place a run or debug test button above the test method within test class.  I am not sure if this is a result of the new dev kit extension but it was working when OmniSharp was used.

I exclusively used those buttons and would appreciate it if I could get them back. One of the draws I have to using VSCode over VS in fact.

However, the new testing panel does allow for debugging. This is not the workflow I am used to or particularly appreciate. Navigating between the testing panel and the tests in your project doesn't work, for example I can't click a test in the test panel and have it open/navigate to the code of that test.

I also tried loading only the test folder with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

If you came here because you too no longer get the links above your methods in your test classes.

Well this all happened soon as I was "recommended" to install c# dev kit, while i thought this was required now, due to some change.  It turns out you do not need c# dev kit.   The dev kit adds behaviors more akin to Visual Studio.  While that's great, I am not using VSCode because I want it to be more like Visual Studio.  You really only need C# base language support.

Unfortunately, removing the dev kit does remove the test tab, test overview.  but I never had that in the first place!  There was more wrong with that test tab than was right anyway.